# Set dialog dim overlay below Toolbar Android

Tags: android, xml, dialog, toolbar

I have layout that consist of toolbar, content, and bottom navigation view. I have managed to setting the dialog layout to be below toolbar. But i haven't found a way to do that for the Dim. I want to make Dim of dialog is start below the toolbar, so that my toolbar will not be overlayed. Is there any workaround for that? Like changing the position or give it some top margin. Thanks.